# Difference between sandbox and production for PushNotification

Tags: ios, iphone

I have the following code, which functions in a sandbox environment:

```
def send_push_notification(user, message):
    ns = apns.APNs(
        use_sandbox=True,
        cert_file="certs/CCert.pem",
        key_file="certs/CKey.pem",
    )
    token_hex = user.push_notification_token
    payload = apns.Payload(alert=message, sound="default")
    return ns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

What would be the difference if I were to set `use_sandbox=False`? What are the differences in the two environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two environments for APNS, namely development (sandbox) and production. For each environment, you need different certificates and send the payload to the corresponding gateway. and also for one iOS device, there are one token for development and one for production.

For detailed information, you can refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) and also [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) is much helpful, since you are using [PyAPNs](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs), you can refer it if necessary.