# How to choose the Push Notification type when buidling iOS ipa

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

There are two types of push notification cert.

1) sandbox

2) production

If I'm building an in-house distribution cert to build an ipa. Which push notification will work? Which one should be use?

Comment: You use both. I mean, You use the Sandbox notifications while you are developing, and when you are uploading the ipa to the appstore then you'll use the production notifications cert.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663347/difference-between-sandbox-and-production-for-pushnotification

Comment: I'm building in-house distribution ipa, as stated above. Which cert will work? Sandbox or production?

Comment: Take a look to @Oleh Zayats answer. That is what i wanted to say.

Comment: @user1872384 Production

Answer (score 2):

You use both `production` push cert and `development` push certificate.

`Sandbox` works ONLY with `development builds`.

The `production` push notifications will automatically work when you download the app from the App Store, deliver via TestFlight or when you make an AdHoc version of your App.

P.S. Apple made it possible to create a single certificate for the two environments. The cert that works for "debug" builds will also work for production/TestFlight builds.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to say. Good job.

Comment: what if I select "save for enterprise deployment" when creating ipa?

Comment: @user1872384 I've did an in-house app, Enterprise Deployment also, the app used production cert when delivered. Did you try it? Do you have issues?